# Excluir dados do Banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou trabalhando com um banco de dados que tem 2 tabelas,processos e movimentoprocessos,preciso excluir um dado da tabela processos,mas o campo ID da tabela processo é uma foreing key na tabela movimentoprocessos.Estou utilizando PHP e MYSQL.

Comment: Qual regra de integração você usou no relacionamento? ON UPDATE, ON DELETE ...?

Comment: Eu utlizei on DELETE

Comment: Então você só precisa fazer a query de delete e executá-la.
Você quer ajuda com código fonte, ou sua dúvida era apenas a respeito de que forma seria o comportamento?

Comment: Ah sim,muito obrigado,minha dúvida era mais a forma que eu ira fazer.

Comment: Caso alguma resposta foi útil, marque como respondida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso a regra de integridade seja **ON DELETE**, você só precisa executar a query de exclusão  que os dados também serão excluídos na outra tabela.

Segue um exemplo de deleção quando a regra de integridade é ON DELETE [aqui](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/).

Caso queira ajuda com o código , comente aqui.

Se a resposta foi útil , não esqueça de marcar como respondida.

Answer (score 0):

Isso está acontecendo porque o dado que você está tentando excluir está amarrado com a outra tabela. Então você precisa alterar ou excluir esse dado tirando a amarração(O campo que está com a chave primaria do dado da tabela MOVIMENTOPROCESSOS) e depois excluir o dado.

Comment: Ok,obrigado pela ajuda!